# Can i get all thumbnails in my specific folder?

Tags: c#, uwp, thumbnails

I want to get a thumbnail image of all photo files in a specific folder.
(Example: My C: \ Mypic)

I found another way to get a single thumbnail image, but this isn't exactly what i want

```
async private Task<BitmapImage> Thumbnail_call()
    {
        var files = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
        var thumb = await files[0].GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView);            
        var bitm = new BitmapImage();
        bitm.SetSource(thumb);
        return bitm;
    }
```

I think that i have to use foreach sentence

Can you give me a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP app, you can access certain file system locations by default. Apps can also access additional locations through the [file or folder picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers), or by declaring capabilities. See [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) for more details about accessing the folders or files.

After you get the specific folders, you can get all thumbnails in it as the following code.

```
async private Task<List<BitmapImage>> GetThumbnails(StorageFolder folder)
{
    List<BitmapImage> BitmapImageList = new List<BitmapImage>();
    var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var thumb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView);
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(thumb);
        BitmapImageList.Add(bitmap);
    }
    return BitmapImageList;
}
```